# php json_decode не работает внутри exec

Tags: php, json, exec

Есть php скрипт, который с удаленного сайта с помощью curl читает объемный массив данных в json-формате, потом его декодирует с помощью json_decode и обрабатывает. Если запустить скрипт через браузер, все работает корректно.
Стоит запустить скрипт через exec, валится на json_decode.
json_last_error и json_last_error_msg ничего в лог не пишут.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Дополните вопрос примером запроса.

Comment: с какой ошибкой валится то?

Comment: а зачем запускать exec?

Comment: exec - потому что не надо ждать ответ

Comment: нет кода ошибки, просто тишина после json_decode